# Переходы между routes с помощью scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Как осуществить переходы между `route` с помощью прокрутки мыши?**

Может есть еще какие то способы `react routes` + `scrollUp/scrollDown` ?

```
     import React, { Component } from "react";

    <Menu pageWrapId={ "reveal" } className="Main-menu" outerContainerId={ "reveal" } right width={ '515px' }  >
      <NavLink activeClassName='active' to="/" exact={true} >Главная</NavLink>
      <NavLink activeClassName='active' to="/about" >О нас</NavLink>
      <NavLink activeClassName='active' to="/products">Продукты</NavLink>
      <NavLink activeClassName='active' to="/partners">Партнеры</NavLink>
      <NavLink activeClassName='active'  to="/portfolio">Портфолио</NavLink>
      <NavLink activeClassName='active'  to="/contact">Контакты</NavLink>
    </Menu>

    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path={this.props.history} component={About} />
    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
    <Route path="/partners" component={Partners} />
    <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
```

Comment: Вообще переходы по роутам с помощью скролла - это обычные якоря на странице. Вот тут почитай. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: мне нужно осуществлять переходы по `route` прокруткой мыши

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно повесить обработчик на scroll событие для window, в котором согласно логике вашего приложения отслеживать позицию по вертикали и определять какой роут необходимо осуществить.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

handleScroll: function(event) {
    let scrollTop = event.srcElement.body.scrollTop;

    // здесь будет логика определения ваших роутов

    // затем, в случае если react-router < 4
    this.props.router.push('/foo-route');
    // в случае если react-router >= 4
    this.props.history.push('/foo-route');
},
```

Comment: Если не сложно, посмотрите более поздний вопрос, лучше описание [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814842/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-scroll-in-react]