# Как отловить событие scroll? In react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно отловить событие `scroll` вверх и вниз, и в зависимости от этого менять `this.props.history`. Получилось отследить скролл, но не могу сообразить как менять `url` в зависимости от прокрутки.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        menuOpen: false,
        urlSite: ['/', '/about', '/products', '/partners', '/portfolio', '/contact']
    };
}
scrollSite(y){
    if(y < 0){
        console.log('slide up')
    } else {
        console.log('slide down')
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
        this.scrollSite(e.wheelDelta);
    })
}
<div className="content">
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
    <Route path="/partners" component={Partners} />
    <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный вариант (главное чтобы страница скролилась):

Создаете в компоненте переменную в которую будете записывать последнее значение (по умолчанию 0) и переменную для направления (по умолчанию false - она нужна для того чтобы не делать лишние изменения в this.props.history):

```
class ... extends ... {
    lastScroll = 0
    directionDown = false

    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Далее переписываете свою функцию:

```
handleScroll = () => {
    // Берете значение
    const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    // Сравниваете 2 значение
    if (scrollTop > this.lastScroll && !this.directionDown) {
        console.log('down');
        this.directionDown = true;
        // здесь манипуляции с this.props.history
    } else if (scrollTop < this.lastScroll && this.directionDown) {
        console.log('up');
        this.directionDown = false;
        // здесь манипуляции с this.props.history
    }
    this.lastScroll = scrollTop;
}
```

Если нужно чтобы просто отслеживалось вниз и вверх (не изменения, было вверх стало вниз), то уберите все что связано с directionDown.

Comment: почему то это не срабатывает, в консоли пусто

Comment: @max scrollTop меняется в функции?

Comment: @max исправил ответ, true => false

Comment: все равно ничего

Comment: @max вообще ничего в консоли не появляется? scrollTop меняется в функции? Чему оно равно? Не undefined?

Comment: В консоли ничего, `scrollTop` не меняется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76093/discussion-between---and-max).